# How to check over a DataFrame and return columns that contain particular strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `df`:

```
                                  0      1      2           3          4
3                 Services rendered            2000        HK$’000 HK$’000
5  Audit and audit related services            999           1,800   9,999
8              financial statements  HK$’000   788           600     1,233,456
```

I want to capture columns which have both currency and financial number e.g. `HK$’000` and `1,800` or `600`.

- In this case, `df[3]` and `df[4]` is the column in interested, **not** `df[1]` or `df[2]`

The desire result is returning a DataFrame: `df[[3, 4]]` as the following

```
    3          4
3  HK$’000 HK$’000
5  1,800   9,999
8  600     1,233,456
```

I tried

```py
df_fin = df[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('HK')) | df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('\d,?\d*'))]
df_fin.iloc[:, df_fin.any().to_list()]
```

but it captures `df[1]` and `df[2]` too. How may I have the desired result?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to get a specific column in advance, why not simply do this.`df=df[[3,4]]`

Comment: @r-beginners because the columns-in-interested's name are not guarantee. In real tasks you do not know where these columns will be but you know there it follows a pattern. i.e. it comes with a currency first and financial number for the rest of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could break it down into steps, to make it easier to pull off. The assumption here is that the entire dataframe is just strings :

Create regexes :

```
regex1 = "HK\$’\d+$"
regex2 = "^\d+[\d,]+$"
```

Filter for the first regex :

```
df = df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(regex1)).any()]
df

    1       3         4
3   None    HK$’000 HK$’000
5   None    1,800   9,999
8   HK$’000 600     1,233,456
```

Now, filter for the second regex:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(regex2)).any()]
df


     3        4
3   HK$’000 HK$’000
5   1,800   9,999
8   600     1,233,456
```

Answer (score 0):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.replace` with `pandas.Series.str.isnumeric`:

```
d = {"HK\$’": "1", ",": ""}
df = df.astype(str)
cols = []
for c in df:
    if df[c].str.contains("HK\$’").any():
        if df[c].replace(d, regex=True).str.isnumeric().all():
            cols.append(c)
print(df[cols])
```

Output:

```
         3          4
3  HK$’000    HK$’000
5    1,800      9,999
8      600  1,233,456
```

Comment: what happens if there is a column is only numeric but there is no currency..? i need them both in the same column

Comment: mind to explain more? i do not see the rationale here for the `astype(str)` since every element in the dataframe is `str`

Comment: @chris_2020 Updated. Please let me know if it yields expected output ;)

Comment: in the 2nd `if` clause, will it be the same if i use `df[c].str.contains("\d,\d*").any()`? it sounds more pythonic, if yes, i think the `d` is also not necessary..